# How to make my Python code read from the second line for my lexer

Tags: python, file, compiler-construction, lexer

I am busy building a small compiler that reads the file, finds keywords and then does what the keyword specifies. I have an issue that it starts reading the file from the begining each time and icould not find a way to solve this problem with out nested if statements.

swift.py:

```
from sys import *
import re

tokens = ["PRINT"]

def open_file(filename):
    with open (filename, "r") as filecontents:
        data = filecontents.read().replace('\n', ' ')
return data

def lex(filecontents):
    words = filecontents.split(" ")
    filecontents = list(filecontents)
    word = []
    states = 0
    statesRun = False
    statesBool = True
    string = ""
    stringAmount = 0
    toks = ""
    i = 0.0
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[int(i)].upper() == tokens[0].upper():
            word.append("PRINT")
            for char in filecontents:
                toks += char
                if char == "\"":
                    if states == 0: 
                        statesRun = True
                        if char == "\"" and statesBool == False:
                            states = 1
                            string += char
                            statesRun = False
                        statesBool = False
                    elif states == 1:
                        statesRun = False
                if statesRun:
                    string += char
            stringAmount += 1
            word.append("STRING:" + string)
            string = ""
            statesBool = True
            statesRun = False
            states = 0
    return word

def parse(toks):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(toks)):
        if toks[i].upper() + " " + toks[i+1][0:6].upper() == "PRINT STRING":
            print(toks[i+1][7:])
            i+=2

class core():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    toks = lex(data)
    parse(toks)

core()
```

test.swift:

```
print "Hello"
print "jobs"
```

input in cmd:

```
python swift.py test.swift
```

I have researched programming languages, compilers, interpreters, parsers, lexers and syntax. I based this code of of this youtube seris(episode 1 - 2)
[episode 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b3WmftYBaBA)

Comment: So, your question is how do you start from line 2 instead of line 1? You could just put in a `filecontents.readline()` before you read the rest into `data`.

Comment: Note that your first `return` is bad placed as it shoud be indented to not be on the same line than the `def`

Comment: really your grammar/lexer is broken if you have to skip the first line ... why not just fix your lexer/grammar

Comment: oh perhaps thats what you are actually asking for

Comment: Off topic: hey @Esca, what country is your avatar's flag from?

Comment: the flag was from a game about colonization in a steam punk era

Comment: The output is "Hello" "Hello" because when it finds print it iterates through the entire document untill it finds "" what i want it to do is start the iteration on the sameline that it finds the word print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works now thanks to Markku K!

```
from sys import *
import re

lines = []
tokens = ["PRINT"]

def open_file(filename):
    data = open(filename, "r")
    for line in data.readlines():
        lines.append(line.replace('\n', ''))
    with open (filename, "r") as filecontents:
        data = filecontents.read().replace('\n', ' ')
    return data

def lex(filecontents):
    words = filecontents.split(" ")
    filecontents = list(filecontents)
    word = []
    states = 0
    statesRun = False
    statesBool = True
    string = ""
    stringAmount = 0
    toks = ""
    i = 0.0
    z = 0
    for i in range(len(words)):
        if words[int(i)].upper() == tokens[0].upper():
            word.append("PRINT")
            for char in lines[z]:
                toks += char
                if char == "\"":
                    if states == 0: 
                        statesRun = True
                        if char == "\"" and statesBool == False:
                            states = 1
                            string += char
                            statesRun = False
                        statesBool = False
                    elif states == 1:
                        statesRun = False
                if statesRun:
                    string += char
            stringAmount += 1
            word.append("STRING:" + string)
            string = ""
            statesBool = True
            statesRun = False
            states = 0
            z += 1
    return word

def parse(toks):
    i = 0
    while(i < len(toks)):
        if toks[i].upper() + " " + toks[i+1][0:6].upper() == "PRINT STRING":
            print(toks[i+1][7:])
            i+=2

def run():
    data = open_file(argv[1])
    toks = lex(data)
    parse(toks)

run()
```